# Android style problems on Nexus 7 (using custom style)

Tags: android, android-styles, android-fullscreen

I work on an Android app and everything works fine. Recently, I wanted to have a custom style, so I added it to styles.xml and in the manifest I associate the activities with this theme (`android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"`):

```
<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Everything works fine on my HTC Android fine (with Android 4.1). But if I install the app on my Nexus 7 Tablet (with android 4.4), the respective activity is totally distorted.

How an activity looks on my phone:

[image: How it looks on my phone]

How the activity looks on my tablet:

[image]

Comment: I have seen something similar before, but for a very specific case... By chance have you implemented a custom onDraw() or use Canvas in some other way?

Comment: @matiash : This is a very simple list, no use of onDraw() or Canvas.